# RegEx Phone Number in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have had some type of phone number is 123-1234567 and (321) 1234567, and then I made the phone number as:

```
123-1234567, 
Area Code = 123, 
Number = 1234567

(321) 1234567, 
Area Code = 321, 
Number = 1234567
```

I use patterns `(.) (\\ d +) (.) (\\ d +)`, but the results do not match expectations of `123-1234567`

The program code that I use

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
private static Pattern telp = Pattern.compile("(.)(\\d+)(.)(\\d+)");

   public static void testNomor(String s){

       Matcher m = telp.matcher(s);

       if (m.matches()) {
           System.out.println(s + "\nArea Code = " +m.group(2)+"\nPhone Number = " + m.group(4) + "\n");
       }  else {
           System.out.println(s+" phone number is invalid");
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       testNomor("(321)1234567");
       testNomor("123-1234567");
       testNomor("(1433)-123 456");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it's not 100% clear what you want to match in your example,
and I'm not familiar too much with the american telephone numbers,
but you could give the pattern

```
\\((\\d+)\\)-?(\\d+)\\D*?(\\d*)
```

and

```
(\\d+)-?(\\d+)\\D*?(\\d*)
```

a shot,
i.e:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
private static Pattern telp1 = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)\\)-?(\\d+)\\D*?(\\d*)");
private static Pattern telp2 = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)-?(\\d+)\\D*?(\\d*)");

   public static void testNomor(String s){

       Matcher m = telp1.matcher(s);
       Matcher m2 = telp2.matcher(s);

             if (m.matches()) {
       System.out.println(s + "\nArea Code = " +m.group(1)+"\nPhone Number = " + m.group(2) + m.group(3) + "\n");
   } else if (m2.matches()) {
       System.out.println(s + "\nArea Code = " +m2.group(1)+"\nPhone Number = " + m2.group(2) + m2.group(3) + "\n");

   }  else {
       System.out.println(s+" phone number is invalid");
   }
}
```

This gives me:

```
(321)1234567
Area Code = 321
Phone Number = 1234567

123-1234567
Area Code = 123
Phone Number = 1234567

(1433)-123 456
Area Code = 1433
Phone Number = 123456
```

There are probably more sophisticated regex available in the www,
which validate phone numbers better than I do here. Note that I updated
my post for the reason mentioned in the comment below.

Of course you can combined the two pattern with the or operator `|` and using positive lookahead/lookbehind and then combine the `if` and `else if` into one expression two remove the code duplication I introduced for illustrating purposes.

Comment: You have to be careful with the pattern I gave you, it does not ensure
that you have matching parentheses in all cases. You would have to modify
the pattern a little bit though. There is also nothing wrong with using two distinct patterns and try to match them separately.